# Is there a Rails admin interface that supports MongoDB and Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, devise, admin-interface

I recently switched to MongoDB and I am wondering if I can continue using any of the popular admin interface solutions, such as ActiveScaffold and Typus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ActiveAdmin https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin is a great tool for the admin interface creation. And I believe sooner or later they add mongoid support.

Right now there's some patch for it: https://github.com/ebeigarts/mongoid_active_admin_app
I didn't try it myself though.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work in Rails 3.2.2, I get the error: `<module:ActiveAdmin>': superclass mismatch for class ResourceController (TypeError)` at line 22 of this file you mentioned: https://github.com/ebeigarts/mongoid_active_admin_app/blob/master/config/initializers/active_admin_mongoid_patches.rb

Comment: still no support for mongoid :(

Answer (score 15):

You can try [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin):

> a Rails engine that provides an easy-to-use interface for managing your data.
>
> #### Features
>
> - CRUD any data with ease
> - Custom actions
> - Automatic form validation
> - Search and filtering
> - Export data to CSV/JSON/XML
> - Authentication (via Devise or other)
> - Authorization (via CanCanCan or Pundit)
> - User action history (via PaperTrail)
> - Supported ORMs
>
>   - ActiveRecord
>   - Mongoid

Comment: Mongoid is supported now. You'll get nested forms for embedded documents automatically which is cool. Really.

Answer (score 1):

if your using Mongoid as your ORM, then active_admin should do the job.. apply this [patch](https://github.com/ebeigarts/mongoid_active_admin_app/blob/master/config/initializers/active_admin_mongoid_patches.rb) to get it working

this disables some functionalities (mostly filters because active_admin relies on meta_search and that gem only supports active_record)

- Fixes ActiveAdmin sorting
- Disables ActiveAdmin Filters/Search
- Disables ActiveAdmin Comments

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find this page on MongoDB's site to be the best help:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

There are many admin applications available, some in browser, some fat client, etc. that you can use for admin and maintaining your Mongo backend.

I am a .Net programmer so I have used only MongoVUE, but one that caught my eye that I might check out and it should be platform agnostic is [JMongoBrowser](http://edgytech.com/jmongobrowser/)

I'd bet plenty options will work with a RAILS setup.